# How to read data from socket connection - android

Tags: android, sockets

I've got TCP client app which successfully negotiates connection to server and receives buffered output, but what I need to know is how to read server responses without waiting to buffer to fill out or server to end connection.
In this loop:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   ...some code here...         
}
```

mine app just freezes.
How to read just one line or empty string if buffer is empty and continuing to execute a program?
Is it possible to timeout this reading, to give server some time to respond?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying protocol should provide some kind of synchronisation, like HTTP's `Content-Length` or `\n\r`.

Otherwise, you'll get blocked even if your program reads byte by byte.

Or you could use a [non-blocking socket](http://xsocket.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I don't have that kind of trouble with win apps. I can easily read server answers line by line or get notified about no answer with 500 ms timeout without interface freeze. Is this not possible with standard android libraries?

Comment: ah, UI freeze. That's different. Everything related to UI in Android runs in the "main" thread. I'm afraid you will have to read the socket in a separate thread. Please have a look to http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html . This may help as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031280/threading-in-android